# svn commit to a new repository from an existing repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, versioning

I would like to commit codes from an existing repository in svn to a new repository in svn. how is this possible? should i disconnect from the existing repository to commit to a new repository or is it possible to commit without disconnecting? thanks.

Comment: you have to disconnect

Comment: @DevZer0 thanks.. i disconnected and made changes finally!